# Bootstrap 4 pills clicked content showing below and/or not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So the problem is when I click on the last two pills "Activity" and "Impact" and shows the information right below the pill content of "STEMuli" (after clicking STEMuli). But the weird part is when you click on "Who we are" and then click on "Activity" or "Impact" it doesn't do anything. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out, I looked for lingering div tags and at one point I had it working when I had only 3 pill options. But right when I threw in this fourth item in it threw it out of sync. Any suggestions?

Also please enjoy my **Infinity War** placeholder images.

```css
.popover-header{
  color:#000000;
}
li{
  color:#000000;
}
#border{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}
#row{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.logo{
  z-index:0;
}
h5{
  color: #ffffff;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.row__inner {
  -webkit-transition: 450ms -webkit-transform;
  transition: 450ms -webkit-transform;
  transition: 450ms transform;
  transition: 450ms transform, 450ms -webkit-transform;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.tile {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 450ms all;
  transition: 450ms all;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
          transform-origin: center left;
}
.tile__img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}
.tile__details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(0,0,0,0.9)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  -webkit-transition: 450ms opacity;
  transition: 450ms opacity;
}
.tile__details:after,
.tile__details:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: #000;
}

.tile__details:before {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
.tile:hover .tile__details {
  opacity: 1;
}
.tile__title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row__inner:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-62.5px, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-62.5px, 0, 0);
}
.row__inner:hover .tile {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.row__inner:hover .tile:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 1;
}
.tile:hover ~ .tile {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(125px, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(125px, 0, 0);
}
a:hover{
  color: #F1D302;
}
.checkbox-wrapper {
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
}
.card-img-top {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

.btn-xlong {
    padding: 10px 50px;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: normal;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
}
.steps-form-3 {
  width: 2px;
  height: 470px;
  position: relative; }
  .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column; }
    .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3:before {
      top: 14px;
      bottom: 0;
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      width: 2px;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #7283a7; }
    .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 {
      height: 150px;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative; }
      .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3.no-height {
        height: 50px; }
      .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 p {
        margin-top: 0.5rem; }
      .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 button[disabled] {
        opacity: 1 !important;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important; }
      .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 .btn-circle-3 {
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        border: 2px solid #59698D;
        background-color: white !important;
        color: #59698D !important;
        border-radius: 50%;
        padding: 18px 18px 15px 15px;
        margin-top: -22px; }
        .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 .btn-circle-3:hover {
          border: 2px solid #4285F4;
          color: #4285F4 !important;
          background-color: white !important; }
        .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 .btn-circle-3 .fa {
          font-size: 1.7rem; }
::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 0px;
  height:5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: insert 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.spacing{
  padding: 6px;
}

/*This css file defines the color scheme and font of all of the webpages so import into every new webpage*/

body {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
  background-color: #9E2B25;
  color:#FDFFFC;
}
.button{
    background-color:#0267C1;
}
.nav-pills .nav-link.active
{
  background-color: #0267c1;

}
h3{
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cardimg
{
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>STEMuli</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/css/mastercss.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/profile.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="/js/moment.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <!--This is where the logo is-->

  <div id="row" class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
    <img src="https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/avengers-infinity-war3.jpg?quality=98&strip=all&w=782" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
  </div>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 justify-content-center" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-we-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-we" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-we" aria-selected="true">
        <h3>Who We Are</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-STEM-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-STEM" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-STEM" aria-selected="false">
        <h3>STEMuli</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-activity-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-activity" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-activity" aria-selected="false">
        <h3>Activity</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-impact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-impact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-impact" aria-selected="false">
        <h3>Impact</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-we" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-we-tab">
      <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
        <video width="700" controls>
<source src="/img/IMG_0021.mov" type="video/mp4">
<source src="/img/IMG_0021.mov" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
        <h5>Texas Capital Bank’s mission is helping businesses grow and communities prosper. Our approach to banking is to find the best people, develop the best relationships, and build something great together.</h5></blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-STEM" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
      <div class="row">
        <h2 style="padding:20px;">Credit</h2>
        <div class="row__inner">
          <a href='#.' onclick="redirectbankon()">
            <div class="tile" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-html="true" title="Description" data-content="The Bank On It module provides an overview of banking services and is designed to help participants build a positive relationship with a financial institution.
            ">
              <div class="tile__media">
                <img class="tile__img" src="http://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/avengers-infinity-war-imax-poster.jpg" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="tile__details">
                <div class="tile__title">
                  <h5>Bank On It</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-activity" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-activity-tab">PLEASE SHOW!</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-impact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-impact-tab">PLEASE SHOW!</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/redirect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/form.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
      })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please provide a minimal example, it's really hard to see the problem without looking at your code to find that your activity tab only contains "please show !", by dumping useless images and text and being concise, we'll be able to help you way faster and better ... also you problem seems to be you forgot to close a tag

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to close a html tag somewhere, by just adding `<\div>` once before your 3rd pill, it works perfectly

the first reason we want minimal examples is to prevent that, with a small file and good indentation, you would be able to spot the issue instantly

Comment: I am using beautify on Atom and somehow I failed to see the "row_inner" tag was missing a div. I'll definitely own up to not paying attention to the smaller details.

Answer (score 0):

Acutely i checked all your code there is nothing wrong i just removed the data inside because it looks too mess to see and i just put just a test text and its working fine you can check it here

```
fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ew0xb5m3/
```

Comment: by reformating OP's code (wich was his job to do so) you deleted an opening tag without deleting a closing tag (wich was missing). that solved the issue ;)